# How to increase the height of textField acc. to the text entered

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I am using a textField in which when user enters the text and after few words the text goes on hiding from the start.So is there a way to increase the height of textField according to the text entered.
Now it looks like this..
[image: Now it looks like this]

Please let me know what should be done to resolve this.